# Google Search Api syntax for excludeTerms

Tags: google-search-api

In the api excludeTerms (string) Identifies a word or phrase that should not appear in any documents in the search results.

If I wanted to exclude job and company what would that look like.
In a google search it would be -job -company, but that does not seem to be working.

Answer (score -1):

Found solution, by experimenting with api explorer.
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/customsearch/v1/

It is just a space between each value.